# Plant identification - small rubbery leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, plant-care

I acquired this plant from a friend recently, but am unsure how to properly care for it! 
The leaves are quarter sized at their largest, and they are stiff and rubbery feeling. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Kalanchoe blossfeldiana. It is a very hardy plant, drought-resistant and pest-resistant.

It needs some pruning if it grows too long and loves brights light. Does not like overwatering.

More info here: https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/flaming-katy.html

It may have very beautiful flowers, but it’s tricky to make it bloom at home.

Comment: That does appear to be it, though this little guy is much smaller than all the pictures I see. It must just be a newer plant. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly, its leaves vary in size depending on age, amount of light, water, season, fertilizers etc. Have fun with this cool plant!